# Stop immediately NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I'm trying to stop my NSTimer (no repeats) immediately but i can't.
my NSTimer do the following code:

```
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer*)timer{
    dispatch_queue_t serverDelaySimulationThread = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxx.serverDelay", nil);
    dispatch_async(serverDelaySimulationThread, ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //CALL WEBSERVICE RESPONSE IN HERE
        });
    });
}
```

Each time textField Did Change, i will invalidate NSTimer and recreate NSTimer!! All i want to execute a request to WEBSERVICES if the Delay time between 2 times user typing characters bigger than 2s. My code is following

```
-(void) textFieldDidChange:(id)sender{
    [MyTimer invalidate];
    MyTimer = nil;
    MyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

But, when i quickly type "ABCD" -> 2s after that, 4 webservices was called. 
How can i stop NSTimer while it unfinished

Tks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer timeInterval is set to 0. So each time you type your timer fires. Change your code to look like this

```
MyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And it should work :)

Comment: In my NSTimer a have add sleep Time and set it to 2s. If i apply your solution, it only increase my sleep time up to 4s. :) tks

Comment: Sorry I have forgot to say that when you set your timer timeInterval to 2.0 seconds you don't need [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
Problem is that when you put your thread to sleep you can't cancel it, it will continue with execution after 2.0 seconds.
So just remove that NSThread sleep and set timer to 2.0 seconds and it will work :)

Comment: Oh! I just want to waiting 2s, within 2s if this Timer is not canceled -> call a WEBSERVICE.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self    selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are implementing textdidchange delegate. So how many times you type text. It will get called. SO inside that you have written four letters. So definitely your NSTimer is calling four times your web service. I would suggest better to use `- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification` So that whenever you enter or tabb out your webservice will called.